# get the highest role from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I currently have an array `u._roles` that is filled with id's from groups like "581199939464462340".
Secondly I have a dictionary where the key is a role id and the value is the name, like `{key: "581199939464462340", value: "Member"}`.

Now I want to get the name of the "highest" role of the array. Currently I have this ugly if statement but I think that can be done better, but how? (The array `u._roles` is read only).

u._roles could look like this:

`["5812040340469414946", "581200340469415946", "581209222700597248"]` so the "highest" would be "581200340469415946" (second if). (And then get the name of this id from the dictionary `roleMap`)

```
var Rank;

if (u._roles.includes("581199939464462340")) {
    Rank = roleMap["581199939464462340"]; // highest
} else if (u._roles.includes("581200340469415946")) {
    Rank = roleMap["581200340469415946"]; //
} else if (u._roles.includes("581214123334041620")) {
    Rank = roleMap["581214123334041620"]; // 
} else if (u._roles.includes("588976480017448988")) {
    Rank = roleMap["588976480017448988"]; //
} else if (u._roles.includes("581203853635223574")) {
    Rank = roleMap["581203853635223574"]; // 
} else if (u._roles.includes("581209222700597248")) {
    Rank = roleMap["581209222700597248"]; // 
} else if (u._roles.includes("592436270031175681")) {
    Rank = roleMap["592436270031175681"]; // lowest
} else {
    Rank = "";
}
```

Highest don't mean the highest number. Its just an order I like to use.

Comment: can you post what is in `u._roles` ?

Comment: its just a normal array but sure I will edit the question

Comment: *Highest don't mean the highest number. Its just an order I like to use.* You have to specify some sort of order into the array maybe through a key, eg  `priority: 1`. What do you mean by the array is read only?

Comment: Is there any relationship between these seemingly random numbers? How many such numbers can exist.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava The order is like I am currently check with the if statements from top to bottom. With read only I mean I cant change anything of the u or u._roles object.

Comment: I like the idea of assigning an integer priority to each role in the map.  You could also use `indexOf` to find it in an array, and let its index be its integer priority.

Comment: @Aditya No, these id's are complete random. There can be many diffrend numbers but I just care about these 7.

Comment: Well if your order is truly random like shown in your if-else block, I cannot think of an algorithm to improve it. *I cant change anything of the u or u._roles* How does that work?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I mean, I _could _change it but I get a new u element. (This code block is inside a for each loop). And the elements will be new generated each time I get to the loop. That's why I cant change the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just save the right order in an array, loop it and check whether the value is included in roles. If yes `find` will return it and we can put it into roleMap[`findvalue`].

```js
let order = ["581199939464462340", "581200340469415946", "581214123334041620", "588976480017448988", "581203853635223574", "581209222700597248","592436270031175681"],
    roles = ["5812040340469414946", "581200340469415946", "581209222700597248"];

let rank = order.find(v => roles.includes(v)); 

console.log(rank) // => 581200340469415946
```

Replace the rank line in your code with:

```
let rank = roleMap[order.find(v => roles.includes(v))]
```

If your order or amount of elements in orders is likely to change this will be messy, if not, you can just save them for comparison like this.

Comment: can `order` also be a dictionary? so I can directly get the vaule after `.find()` ?

Comment: Dictionaries or objects in this case have no guaranteed order (might have changed recently but that's my current knowledge). So even though you could iterate your dictionary you would have no guarantee you receive the right element. See the code snippet I added at the bottom that directly returns the respective value from your roleMap (which only takes O(1) anyway).

Answer (score 3):

I completely changed this answer with some  new insight. Hopefully this is a bit more helpful.

```
const rolePriority = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4};
const u = {"_roles": ['b','c', 'a']};

const rankNumber = u._roles.reduce((highest, role) => {
  const rank = rolePriority[role];
  return rank < highest ? rank : highest;
}, Infinity);

const rank = rankNumber === Infinity ? "" : roleMap[rankNumber]
```

Comment: So `things` would be `u._roles`?

Comment: I think i misunderstood your question. You have a `u` and `u` has many `roles` assigned. You want to find the highest role and set `Rank` to the label for that role.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly copy the array, then sort it by the role property and take the first element.

```js
var data = [{
    name: "Rank 1",
    role: "5812040340469414946",
  },
  {
    name: "Rank 2",
    role: "581200340469415946"
  },
  {
    name: "Rank 3",
    role: "581209222700597248"
  }
];

// Copy the source array to avoid mutating it using destructuring it
var copy = [...data];

// Sort by role property
var rank = copy.sort((a, b) => (+a.role) - (+b.role))[0].name;
console.log(rank);
```

Comment: While the code is elegant, you are missing the point that the larger number is not the highest in this case. *Highest don't mean the highest number.* - from the question.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava it is unclear what does highest mean in the context of OP