# Google Spreadsheet node.js move a row or sort table

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

Edit: I saw that I am not using the official google api. This is a package based on v3 of the google api. [Here is the npm that I currently use](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet).

[I saw that google api v4 exists](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs) and has many more features than the npm package I currently use, would it be possible with the official v4 api? What would I need to change to use this api?

---

Is it possible to move a row to a specific row (number)?
If not, can I [custom sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57184174/get-the-highest-role-from-array) the entire table again?

This is how I access the table:

```
const GoogleSpreadsheet = require("google-spreadsheet");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const creds = require("./client_secret.json");
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
const tt = promisify(doc.useServiceAccountAuth)(creds);
const info = await promisify(doc.getInfo)();
const sheet = info.worksheets[0];
```

And now I want to edit/update a row, and because the order should be different now if I change the column cell where my table is sorted by, I want to move the row somewhere else. this is how I modify a row:

```
var row = await promisify(sheet.getRows)({
        offset: 1,
        query: 'id = ' + userId      
});

//This row has now a different value and should have a different row number
row[0].role= "value";

//This will update the row, but only on its current position.
promisify(row[0].save)();
```

Pseudo code (how it should look like, row[0] has no attribute that indicates the position):

```
//row[0] role was "" and now "member", the row should be where the other member rows are
row[0].index = IndexOf(AllRows.where(x => x.role == "member")) + 1
```